# Visualizing order of operations

Tags: hold, operators, education, trees, order

```mathematica
TreeForm[HoldForm[ (9-2^2+10 8)/9]]
```

produces this:

[image: operations tree]

Is there a way to use `Divide` instead of `Power` to $-1$ and delete the "HoldForm" node or change it another string? Change the "Times", "Plus", etc. nodes to the result of the operation?

<sup>I'm trying to make trees illustrating the order of operations.</sup>

Comment: `Subtract` and `Divide` are automagically converted (see their respective doc pages for details), but have a look at `ExpressionTree[Unevaluated[(9 - 2^2 + 10 8)/9]]`.

Comment: Is this good?: `Hold[(9 - 2^2 + 10 8)/9] /. Times[x_, Power[b_, -1]] :> HoldForm[Divide][x, b] /. op : Plus | Times | Power -> HoldForm[op] // First // TreeForm`

Answer (score 3):

```mathematica
TreeForm[First[
  Hold[1/9 (9 - 2^2 + (10 8)/7)] //. {x_/b_ :> 
      HoldForm[Divide][x, b]} /. 
   op : Plus | Times | Power -> HoldForm[op]]]
```

[image: tree]

<sup>tip: [Michael E2's comment above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268788/visualizing-order-of-operations?noredirect=1#comment670465_268788) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268788/visualizing-order-of-operations/268791#comment670467_268791)</sup>

Comment: I think the first replacement needs to be `ReplaceRepeated` because of the way replacement matches are handled. Example: `Hold[(9 - 2^2 + 10 8/7)/9] //. {Times[x_, Power[b_, -1]] :> HoldForm[Divide][x, b]} /. op : Plus | Times | Power -> HoldForm[op] // First // TreeForm`.